# Origin of "rape and pillage"

Tags: expressions

My usual sources have failed me in finding the origins of the phrase "rape and pillage". I can't even find anything claiming the oldest written instance. The reason I ask is that depending on the times, the term "rape" has a bit of a different meaning. We take the "rape" in "rape and pillage" today to mean the modern sense. However, I've heard it claimed that the word used in the phrase was using one of the earlier meanings. I don't really want to debate it so much as figure out some actual solid citations for its early use.

Comment: Alas, I should have spelled out more clearly that I already knew rape previously meant to take off with force and/or kidnap. I referenced that it previously had different meanings, but I didn't want to get detailed about it. I will say that I'm skeptical about the "60 years ago" claim, given that the sources I have found trace the definition of sexual violation to the 15th century. I would believe that other definitions coexisted more 60 years ago, especially in literary circles.

Comment: @jep If you need to clarify your question, please edit the question rather than bury stuff in comments. However, please don't edit it in a way which invalidates existing answer(s). If that's not possible, then please ask a new, clearer question: you could link to this one and explain how your new one is different.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm just talking about not making it clear that I didn't need things explained (like older definitions for "rape"), saving people from having to type comment after comment about it.

Answer (score 3):

OED has *rape and pillage* from 1817:

> 1817   J. M. Scott *Blue Lights* Notes 143   To stimulate the avarice, lust, and barbarity of the English soldiery, he had promised, that on the capture of the city, three days should be allowed, for the purposes of rape and pillage.

Its definition is ambiguous in distinguishing exactly what is meant by *rape* in that phrase:

> ***rape and pillage:*** the commission of acts of rape and plunder on a large scale, esp. by members of an invading army. Hence in extended use: despoilment, destruction, or defilement of something, esp. for profit.

However, one might look at the history of the word since OED is a historical dictionary. The sense in the past (when the word first appeared in the fourteenth or fifteenth century) was one of carrying-off:

> 1. The act of taking something by force; *esp.* the seizure of property by violent means; robbery, plundering. Also as a count noun: an instance of this, a robbery, a raid. Now *rare* (chiefly *archaic* and *literary*).
>    <sub>Esp. in later use probably frequently influenced by the use of sense 3, particularly its use in the titles of works of art or literature.</sub>

> 3. The act of carrying off a person by force; esp. the abduction of a woman, usually for the purpose of sexual violation. Also *figurative.* Now *archaic.*
>    <sub>In later use chiefly with reference to events of classical mythology and history, esp. in the titles of works of art, etc.</sub>
>    <sub>Closely allied to sense 2a   and sometimes with the implication of actual sexual violence.</sub>

> 2. a. Originally and chiefly: the act or crime, committed by a man, of forcing a woman to have sexual intercourse with him against her will, esp. by means of threats or violence. In later use more generally: the act of forced, non-consenting, or illegal sexual intercourse with another person; sexual violation or assault.
>    <sub>The precise legal definition of rape has varied over time and between legal systems...</sub>

The earliest use they have of sense 2a comes from 1425, so the two related but separable meanings of forced intercourse and carrying-off (perhaps with the intention of forced intercourse) have co-existed for centuries. Anciently, *rape* meant kidnapping or abduction (cf. the Rape of the Sabine Women, *Sabinae raptae*) but when Shakespeare wrote *The Rape of Lucrece* the meaning had progressed towards the modern sense.

Comment: I would say the mention of "lust" in the 1817 quote makes me tend toward thinking it's the modern sense of sexual violation.

Comment: But one can lust for other things, like power. And avarice is inherently acquisitive.

Comment: While this is true, you usually see those written like "lust for power" rather than just "lust" alone. Since the source is from 1817, I still lean towards it fitting more modern terms. Could be wrong, of course. Would love to see some older references.